# What would be a good way of getting an hippogriff from a goliath tribe?

Tags: dnd-5e, rime-of-the-frostmaiden, goliath

I'm currently playing Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden. I'm embodying Vellynne Harpell a human necromancer wizard.

The GM has told me that I will be showing up mounting a hippogriff that I got from a goliath tribe, and I'm supposed to explain how I got it.

Seeing how competitive goliaths are, I was thinking about telling them I won it on a bet. But I can't think of something not involving physical strength or dexterity.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't handle open ended "looking for ideas" questions here, but you may have some success asking your question at a traditional discussion forum, see here for our curated list: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll try them out.